# Disturbing odd behavior/bug in Python itertools groupby?

Tags: python, parsing, csv, text-parsing, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.groupby` to parse a short tab-delimited textfile. the text file has several columns and all I want to do is group all the entries that have a particular value `x` in a particular column. The code below does this for a column called `name2`, looking for the value in variable `x`. I tried to do this using `csv.DictReader` and `itertools.groupby`. In the table, there are *8* rows that match this criteria so 8 entries should be returned. Instead `groupby` returns two sets of entries, one with a single entry and another with 7, which seems like the wrong behavior. I do the matching manually below on the same data and get the right result:

```
import itertools, operator, csv
col_name = "name2"
x = "ENSMUSG00000002459"
print "looking for entries with value %s in column %s" %(x, col_name)
print "groupby gets it wrong: "
data = csv.DictReader(open(f), delimiter="\t", fieldnames=fieldnames)
for name, entries in itertools.groupby(data, key=operator.itemgetter(col_name)):
    if name == "ENSMUSG00000002459":
        wrong_result = [e for e in entries]
        print "wrong result has %d entries" %(len(wrong_result))
print "manually grouping entries is correct: "
data = csv.DictReader(open(f), delimiter="\t", fieldnames=fieldnames)
correct_result = []
for row in data:
    if row[col_name] == "ENSMUSG00000002459":
        correct_result.append(row)
print "correct result has %d entries" %(len(correct_result))
```

The output I get is:

```
looking for entries with value ENSMUSG00000002459 in column name2
groupby gets it wrong: 
wrong result has 7 entries
wrong result has 1 entries
manually grouping entries is correct: 
correct result has 8 entries
```

what is going on here? If `groupby` is really grouping, it seems like I should only get one set of entries per `x`, but instead it returns two. I cannot figure this out.  *EDIT*: Ah got it it should be sorted.

Comment: This is a common misconception about how ``groupby()`` works, but it is the documented behaviour, I suggest you read the docs a little more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to change your code to force the data to be in key order...

```
data = csv.DictReader(open(f), delimiter="\t", fieldnames=fieldnames)
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(col_name))
for name, entries in itertools.groupby(data, key=operator.itemgetter(col_name)):
    pass # whatever
```

The main use though, is when the datasets are large, and the data is already in key order, so when you have to sort anyway, then using a `defaultdict` is more efficient

```
from collections import defaultdict
name_entries = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    name_entries[row[col_name]].append(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), `groupby()` groups only consecutive occurrences of the same key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your data looks like but my guess is it's not sorted. [groupby works on sorted data](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)